# These files import other files that use a different and incompatible version of Solidity

Tags: solidity, version-pragma

I encountered a problem with VSCode suddenly. It didn't have any problems yesterday, but suddenly this error appeared. When I run the compile command, I receive the following error. I'll send the error and some settings that I think are related to this error. Please help me.[image]

Comment: and I'll send some setting that I think is related to this error:   solidity: {
        compilers: [
            {
                version: "0.8.7",
            },
            {
                version: "0.6.6",
            },
        ],
    },                                                                                                                                                                                          mock confiq: // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol";